# Bash script to download any new version of a file from a webpage of a particular software

Tags: bash, scripts, wget, automation, curl

Let's say I'm creating a script to automate downloading & compiling Nginx from source but one improvement I would like to make is make sure the script would work with new Nginx versions without me having to edit it manually for example right now I have this line: `wget https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.17.9.tar.gz && tar zxvf nginx-1.17.9.tar.gz && rm nginx-1.17.9.tar.gz && cd nginx-1.17.9`

Now that works great for the current version of Nginx as of now but in the future that version will change thus breaking the URL, how do I make the script look for and download any new version without me having to edit it with each update they release?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Nginx provides a 'latest' link but maybe I haven't looked hard enough.

I'm afraid you'll have to perform additional steps to achieve the intended result.

You can either read the directory https://nginx.org/download/ and parse the output to determine the most current version. Then download the relevant file.

Another option is to start from here: https://nginx.org/en/download.html
and fetch the URL under the heading: Mainline version.

For either option you have to use a tool like `curl` or `wget`, parse the output, extract the URL. Or get the job done with a more sophisticated scripting language for example `python` + `requests` module and say goodbye to your sweet one-liner.

You could ask Nginx if they have permanent links for automation purposes though, you probably are not the only one doing that.